# Output workflows associated to all lists in a web application

Tags: 2007, powershell

Still very new to Powershell.  I've adapted a script I found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/6131/) to display information I want to see about workflows for a particular list.  That looks like this:

```
$siteURL="https://mydomain/sites/ericrules/"
$listName="Calendar"
$site=Get-SPSite $siteURL
$web=$site.RootWeb
$list=$web.Lists[$listName]
$wfManager=$site.WorkflowManager
$associationColl=$list.WorkflowAssociations
foreach($association in $associationColl)
{
write-host $association.ParentSite, "List:" $association.ParentList, "Name:" $association.Name, "Description:" $association.Description, "Manual:" $association.AllowManual,"On Create:" $association.AutoStartCreate, "On Change:" $association.AutoStartChange,"Created:" $association.Created, "Modified:" $association.Modified
}
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

How would I adapt and generalize this to start at a singular web application and iterate through all the site collections, sites and subsites, looking at every list and outputting that data?  If it was a nicely formatted text file with the quoted values as headers, that'd be ideal.  A CSV would work too.

I'm still having difficulty figuring out all the for each looping going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for all lists in a farm

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local.Services |? { 
    $_.TypeName -eq "Windows SharePoint Services Web Application" 
} |% {
    $_.WebApplications |% {
        $webapplication = $_
        Write-Host "web app"
        $webapplication.Sites |% {
            $site = $_
            Write-Host $site.Url
            $site.AllWebs |% {
                $web = $_
                Write-Host $web.Url
                $web.Lists |% {
                    $list = $_
                    Write-Host $list.Title
                    #do some stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you just need a particular webapplication use this:

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite "https://mydomain/sites/ericrules/")
$webapplication = $site.WebApplication
```

Filter/Dispose as needed

Then pipe the result into `Export-CSV`

Comment: I'll see if I can get that to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This very long sample configures versioning setting for every site (site collection), site (subsite) and list. You will just have to adapt it with your code.

Please do not use this script in your production environment without further testing :)

**Edit**: Just noticed you are looking for SharePoint 2007 script, this is 2010. Sorry.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

cls
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

function Get-SPList
{
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Position=0, 
            Mandatory=$true, 
            ValueFromPipeline=$true
        )]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$CurrentWeb,
        [Parameter(
            Position=1, 
            Mandatory=$false
        )]
        [string]$Title = $null

    )

    Write-Host $CurrentWeb.Url

    foreach($list in $CurrentWeb.Lists)
    {
        if($list.Hidden -eq $false -and ($Title -eq $null -or $Title -eq ""))
        {
            Write-Output $list
        }
        elseif($list.Title -eq $Title)
        {
            Write-Output $list
        }
    }
}

function Set-SPList()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Position=0, 
            Mandatory=$true, 
            ValueFromPipeline=$true
        )]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]$SPList,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [bool]$EnableVersioning = $null,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [bool]$EnableMinorVersions = $null,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int]$MajorVersionLimit = -1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int]$MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = -1
    )


    if($SPList -ne $null -and $SPList.HasExternalDataSource -eq $false)
    {
        if($EnableVersioning -ne $null)
        {   
            $SPList.EnableVersioning = $EnableVersioning
        }
        if($MajorVersionLimit -gt -1)
        {   
            $SPList.MajorVersionLimit = $MajorVersionLimit
        }

        if($SPList.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
        {
            if($EnableMinorVersions -ne $null)
            {   
                $SPList.EnableMinorVersions = $EnableMinorVersions
            }

            if($MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit -gt -1)
            {
                $SPList.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = $MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit
            }
        }
        $SPList.Update()
    }
}



Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | ForEach-Object {Get-SPList $_ | ForEach-Object {Set-SPList $_ -EnableMinorVersions $true -EnableVersioning $true -MajorVersionLimit 5 -MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit 3}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the script Toni, this is great but I think It'll take me a while to digest it and try to adapt it to 2007 and do what I want it to.

Comment: additionally, his script is for powershell 2.0 - the [parameter] attributes for cmdlet binding are not supported in powershell 1.0.